# Preventing Transfer from Specific Address in ERC20 Smart Contract

Tags: erc-20

We have a ERC20 contract. This contract is currently working. We want to make a change to this contract. We do not want certain addresses to transfer tokens. Is it possible to do this? How should we do it if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's possible or not depends on your contract, but most likely it's not possible.

Once a contract is deployed it's immutable - you can't change it. There exist various architectural patterns which allow you to upgrade contracts, but these are typically not used for basic ERC20 tokens. Also, if you don't know about this, then you probably don't have this functionality.

So the only possibility for you is to deploy a new token and migrate users from the old to the new token, in some fashion.